# How to access and change value of parent window control from child window in C#

Tags: c#, controls, parent

Hi
how can I change text value of text box in parent window from child window..

i.e I have parent window have textbox1 and button and child window has textbox2 and button.
I need to update the value of textbox1 when I enter some text in child window's textbox2.

i did some simple function to do this logically its correct but its not working I have no idea why..

parent.cs

```
namespace digdog
{
    public partial class parent : Form
    {
        public parent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void changeText(string text)
        {
            textbox1.Text = text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Display modal dialog
            child myform = new child();
            myform.ShowDialog();

        }

    }
}
```

child.cs

```
namespace digdog
{
    public partial class child : Form
    {

        public child()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         parent mytexts = new parent();
         mytexts.changeText(textbox2.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

any ideas will be appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of your question from not even an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160143/accessing-control-in-parent-window-from-child-window-in-c

Comment: I simplified it so I can get more answers. do u have any problem with that?

Comment: @RobinVanPersi: it's better to edit your question instead of posting it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating another 'parent' window (which is not visible) and changing its text.  The 'real' parent needs to be accessed by the child.  You could do this via a property on the child that is set in the parents button1_click.

e.g.

in child class

```
public parent ParentWindow {get;set;}
```

in parent button1_click

```
child myform = new child();
child.ParentWindow = this;
m.ShowDialog();
```

in child button1_click

```
ParentWindow.changeText(textbox2.Text)
```

Comment: @ermac2014 and @grantnz; yes this works, but you do not need to implement `ParentWindow` as a property of the "child" form; that property already exists in .NET's `Form` class, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

or simple: 
in the ParentWindow

```
ChildWindow child = new ChildWindow(); 
child.Owner = this;
child.ShowDialog();
```

in the child window

```
this.Owner.Title = "Change";
```

this works pretty cool

Comment: In case anyone is interested, using the ShowDialog owner parameter like this [ child.ShowDialog(this); ] achieves the same result with one less line. Also, this parameter leads me to believe this was the intended purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a new parent.  Reference the parent of the form itself.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parent mytexts = this.Parent as parent;
        mytexts.changeText(textbox2.Text);
    }
```

And this is how you first create the child:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Display modal dialog
        child myform = new child();
        myform.ShowDialog(this);  // make this form the parent
    }
```