# Call Function in Parent Window from Child Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attempting to implement a custom search dialog in a WPF program. The Parent window is a ListView that is bound to an Observable Collection.

I've made a new window with the search form and it is initialized like so:

```
searchForm sf = new searchForm(_QPCollection);
sf.Owner = this;
sf.Show();
```

and I have this function I am trying to call (in the Owner window):

```
public void selectIndex(int index)
{
    ListViewItem toSelect = listView1.Items[index] as ListViewItem;
    toSelect.Focus();
}
```

Then in the Child window (searchForm) attempting to call selectIndex like so:

```
public void SearchJob_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sJob.Text == "" || sJob.Text == null) { return; }
    for (int i = findCount; i < _QPCollectionSearch.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == _QPCollectionSearch.Count - 1) { i = 0; }
        if (_QPCollectionSearch[i].jobNumAndFlow.IndexOf(sJob.Text) > -1)
        {
            findCount = i;
            Owner.selectIndex(i);
        }

    }
}
```

I get the error: System.Windows.Window does not contain a definition for "selectIndex".

The `_QPCollection` is the observable collection that the search will loop through. I have the search logic working, but I cannot seem `Focus()` the index of the ListView in the Parent Window.

My first thought was to have a public function that I could pass the index to and it would do the focus, but I cannot seem to find a way to call function from the Child Window that are in the Parent Window.

Am I approaching this completely wrong? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160396/how-to-access-and-change-value-of-parent-window-control-from-child-window-in-c) seems to be for WinForms but I am sure there is a way to access the Parent Window and its public functions/properties in WPF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cleaner way of handling that scenario would be for your `searchForm` to raise an event.  The parent window could listen for that event and set the focus on its own list view:

```
public class searchForm 
{
    public event EventHandler<SearchEventArgs> SearchResultSelected = delegate { };
}

public class SearchEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

searchForm sf = new searchForm(_QPCollection);
sf.SearchResultSelected += (s, e) => MyListView.SelectedIndex = e.Index;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set the `Owner` like you did, you should be able to call public methods inside the dialogue via `(Owner as MyWindowDerivative).Method()` (if Owner is of type `Window`), what exactly is stopping you from doing that?

Edit: If you are going to go that route you should make sure that `Owner` is always of type `MyWindowDerivative`, e.g. by overwriting the Owner-Property, also prevent parameterless constructors.

Comment: I added a bit more code and the error message this is raises -- that it does not have a definition for Method().

Comment: The problem with that is that searchForm is dependent on MyWindowDerivative, and searchForm cannot be spawned by windows of a different type.  If you don't care about that, then this solution works fine.