# Disabling Button In Parent Form Child Form

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have two forms. One is a parent form with a button and a child form with a radio button. i want to enable/disable Button in parent Form Based on if the Radio Button in Child Form is Enabled. Should i raise an event or there is an alternative way to achieve this.??

Comment: Check this post I think it will help you.

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160396/how-to-access-and-change-value-of-parent-window-control-from-child-window-in-c-s

Answer (score 0):

Events are a nice and robust way to handle this.
They will take a bit more code, but it could be worth it if you want a robust solution that you can extend in the future, etc.

On the other hand, if you just want to quickly solve your problem, there are two more commmon solutions.

when you create the child form, you can pass it a reference to the parrent form that created it (through the constructor)

something like

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 parrentForm;
    public Form2(Form1 parrent)
    {
      parrentForm = parrent;
    }
```

When you create the child form, you pass it the reference

```
//from inside Form1
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
```

You might declare a public method inside Form1

```
public void EnableButton() {
}
```

then call it from form2 with the reference you stored

```
parrentForm.EnableButton();
```

you can even make the button in Form1 public (from the gui, select the button, in the properties pane change the "Accessibility" property to "Public" instead of "Private" which is default.

Then in form2 you could do

```
parrentForm.Button1.Enabled = false;
```

these are all quick and somewhat dirty solutions.
Events are more clear for complex uses.

In the end, go with what makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer above but just to mention, you could use an event as well.

```
public event EventArg RadioButtonHasChanged;
```